# (ag-grid) Animate dynamically added columns

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

As we can see on https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-menu/, when the user checks/unchecks a column from the menu, the grid animates the other columns.

I'm introducing some columns dynamically, by using columnDefs:

```
this.columnDefs = [
  { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 200 },
  { headerName: 'S01F01', hide: this.solver !== 'solver1', field: 'age', width: 90, suppressToolPanel: true },
  ...
];
```

I've bound the hide/show flag to buttons on the UI that will bring a set of columns into the grid when needed. Although the columns show up appropriately, they simply appear instead of animating into the grid. I understand this is because I'm simply updating the columnDefs for the whole grid every time the user clicks the button.

Is there a way for me to display these columns on the click of the button while at the same time triggering the animation?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have this grid property `suppressColumnMoveAnimation=true`, the columns should have animation on by default.
As per [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-animation/#column-animations)

> Column animations are on by default, row animations are off by
>   default. This is to keep with what is expected to be the most common
>   configuration as default.

Comment: That would make sense, however it's not happening on my case.
You can see the specific code I use to update the columns below:

`toggleChange(event) {
    const toggle = event.source;
    if (toggle) {
      const groupbutton = toggle.buttonToggleGroup;
      if (event.value.some(item => item === toggle.value)) {
        groupbutton.value = [toggle.value];
      }
    }

    this.solver = toggle ? toggle.value : '';
    this.setColumnDefs();
  }`

`setColumnDefs = () => {
    this.columnDefs = [
        { headerName: 'Name', field: 'name', width: 200 },
    ...
    ]}`